# how to reshape 3D to 2D with a big number?

Tags: python, reshape

hello i'm trying to reshape an array with shape (70,65536,18) to an array in 2D with shape (4587520,18) but i the result its a 3D array whit the same shape
here its the code

```
img=imagenesTrain[0]
filters= scipy.io.loadmat(os.path.join('data_mp3','filterbank.mat'))['filterbank']
def calculate_filter_response_201822381_201821543(imagen,filters):
    imggray=color.rgb2gray(imagen)
    lista=[]

    for i in range(len(filters[0,0])):
        lista.append(scipy.signal.correlate(imggray,filters[:,:,i],mode='same',method='auto'))
    lineal=np.array(lista)
    lineal=lineal.reshape(256*256,18)
    return lineal
imggray=calculate_filter_response_201822381_201821543(img,filters)

respuesta=[]
for i in imagenesTrain:
    respuesta.append(calculate_filter_response_201822381_201821543(i,filters))

respuesta=np.array(respuesta)
respuesta.reshape(4587520,18)
```

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Answer (score 0):

You need to reassign the array, otherwise nothing happens. Reshape doesn't work in-place:

```
respueste = respueste.reshape(4587520, 18)
```